maven error: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass
When i try to run my automation test cases using maven, I'm getting the below error. I ran project>run as> maven install
    Failed to execute goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.9.16:aggregate (serenity-reports) on project flightmode: Execution serenity-reports of goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.9.16:aggregate failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.9.16:aggregate: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null


[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.9.16
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/XXXXX/.m2/repository/net/serenity-bdd/maven/plugins/serenity-maven-plugin/1.9.16/serenity-maven-plugin-1.9.16.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/XXXX/.m2/repository/net/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/1.9.16/serenity-core-1.9.16.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/23.6-jre/guava-23.6-jre.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/XXXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
........

[ERROR] : Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7a972f12
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException


System Java version: JDK 17.0.12
Maven version: 3.8.3

I tried to run using Java 21 also but still I face same issue,
Also added below things in eclipse.ini file, still face same issue
-Djava.security.manager=allow
--illegal-access=warn
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAME


Could you post the full error (there should be a stack trace)? Where is the error coming from (your code, dependency code, Maven, Eclipse, somewhere else)? Note that error typically means some code was not updated in order to work properly with modern versions of Java. Or the code was updated but you're using an outdated version. Try using the latest versions of things (including the plugins used by Maven).

Note that --illegal-access has no effect as of Java 17.

added more error deatail. i feel some java issue running the code.Not sure where update and what to update

The error seems to be coming from serenity-maven-plugin. You're using version 1.9.16, which appears to be a pretty old version. The latest version (as of this comment) looks to be 4.2.6, but that's a lot of major versions to jump. I couldn't find which specific version this issue was solved for. The latest 1.9.x version looks to be 1.9.45.

In short, it looks like your version of serenity-maven-plugin is out of date and you should upgrade it. Which version you should upgrade to depends on information we don't have. Or perhaps the answer below can help.

Why is this tagged with [tag:java-8]? This error only occurs with Java 9 or higher, when you use software exploiting things of Java 8 or lower. Similarly, your question seems to have nothing to do with [tag:eclipse].

Also upgrade Maven version to 3.9.X latest...

One of the options to solve this problem is to use the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable. This variable is automatically applied to all JVM runs, and any options specified to it are added to the command line used by the JVM to configure the runtime environment.
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"

For more detailed information, see the article "Environment Variables and System Properties".
Another solution is to use the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable. This variable contains parameters used to start up the JVM running Maven and can be used to supply additional options to it.
export MAVEN_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"

Starting with Maven 3.3.1+ you can define JVM configuration via .mvn/jvm.config file which means you can define the options for your build on a per project base.
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

For more information, see the article "Configuring Apache Maven".

That might move the time point of required updating only a bit into the future... the real issue is that the plugin which is used should be upgrade....
